# sql server reports using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I was trying to learn sql server report building so I started by using the SQL Server builder intelligent development studio. I created a few .rdl files and they run fine when I run them from visual studio individually. I do not have a report server but I would like to call these report files from a web application. Is there anyway this can be done or should I resort to just using a dataset and make db requests. I would prefer to use the reports but since the sql server version I am using does not have the report management portion installed and I do not have admin permissions to reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28VS.90%29.aspx) control to add your projects.

And you need in in [local mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251704%28VS.90%29.aspx): no web server needed

Edit: need to download it (there are 3 versions BTW)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=CC96C246-61E5-4D9E-BB5F-416D75A1B9EF

Comment: thanks for your response, I am using visual studio 2010, silverlight application, and do not see the report viewer control but will resort to a basic web application in vs 2008 and use that. thanks

Comment: @vbNewbie: you can download it.

Comment: not sure if you will see this but what do I do in the event report generation takes a really long time depending on the query and I wanted the user to be able to see something in a few seconds if they clicked on a report